# Check the previous row and find when the number change to zero in R

Tags: r, dataframe, select, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data like this:

```
d <- data.frame(
  ab = c(3, 4, 2, 6),
  dur_1 = c(32, 1, 3, 4),
  dur_2 = c(27, 9, 26, 5),
  dur_3 = c(25, 8, 21, 48),
  dur_5 = c(0, 4, 0, 42),
  dur_6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
  dur_7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
  cd = c(45, 67, 34, 78)
)
```

What I want to do is make a new column `pre_dur`.
`pre_dur` is the last nonnegative value of previous rows for the variables starts with `dur_`.
So, to get `pre_dur`, scan through the `dur_` variables in the previous row, find where the number starts to change zero. The very last nonnegative number is the value that I want.

My expected output should be like this:

```
d1<-data.frame(ab=c(3,4,2,6),
               dur_1=c(32,1,3,4),
               dur_2=c(27,9,26,5),
               dur_3=c(25,8,21,48),
               dur_5=c(0,4,0,42),
               dur_6=c(0,0,0,0),
               dur_7=c(0,0,0,0),
               cd=c(45,67,34,78),
               pre_dur=c(NA,25,4,21))
```

Actually the code below works:

```
d1 <- d %>%
  mutate(pre_dur = case_when(lag(dur_7) > 0 ~ lag(dur_7),
                             lag(dur_6) > 0 ~ lag(dur_6),
                             lag(dur_5) > 0 ~ lag(dur_5),
                             lag(dur_3) > 0 ~ lag(dur_3),
                             lag(dur_2) > 0 ~ lag(dur_2),
                             lag(dur_1) > 0 ~ lag(dur_1),
                             TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

However, in my actual data, the natural number after `dur_` can be changed. So I need a generalized code. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this solution?

```
library(tidyverse)
temp <- d %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ab) %>% 
  group_by(ab) %>% 
  mutate(out = ifelse(value == 0, lag(value), 0)) %>% 
  filter(out != 0) 
  
# bind_cols(d,  pre_dur = c(NA, temp$out[2:nrow(temp)]))

bind_cols(d,  pre_dur = lag(temp$out))
```

This assumes that once a value drops to 0, then it doesn't increase.  If this isn't the case, then the `ifelse` statement needs to capture this.

Comment: I think you meant `temp$out[2:nrow(temp)]`

Comment: I think so too. If I use `temp$out[2:nrow(out)]`, I get an error.  `temp$out[2:nrow(temp)]` works fine, but `pre_order` should be shifted one row .

Comment: My mistake - Corrected

Comment: If I use this: ```d1<-bind_cols(d,  pre_dur = c(NA,temp$out[2:nrow(temp)]))
d1$pre_dur<-lag(d1$pre_dur)
```      It's fine. but, the second value of `pre_dur` is `NA`.   I want only first value to be `NA` in this case. I wonder if I can make lag `pre_dur` from the code you provided to us.

Comment: When I run it, the first value is NA.  Instead, look at the updated answer.  Another, better way of shifting the output.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know your answer was updated. It works now!

Answer (score 1):

First, find the value for each group, then, lag it once. We could do it using `rowwise()`, but it's probably faster and more readable to transform it into long format and back again. I.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d |>
    pivot_longer(starts_with("dur")) |>
    mutate(pre_dur = last(value[value > 0]), .by = "ab") |>
    pivot_wider() |>
    mutate(pre_dur = lag(pre_dur))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 9
     ab    cd pre_dur dur_1 dur_2 dur_3 dur_5 dur_6 dur_7
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3    45      NA    32    27    25     0     0     0
2     4    67      25     1     9     8     4     0     0
3     2    34       4     3    26    21     0     0     0
4     6    78      21     4     5    48    42     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

A way in base using `max.col` with `last`.

```r
i <- which(startsWith(names(d), "dur"))
j <- max.col(d[i] > 0, "last")
cbind(d, pre_dur = c(NA, d[cbind(seq_len(nrow(d)), i[j])][-nrow(d)]))
#  ab dur_1 dur_2 dur_3 dur_5 dur_6 dur_7 cd pre_dur
#1  3    32    27    25     0     0     0 45      NA
#2  4     1     9     8     4     0     0 67      25
#3  2     3    26    21     0     0     0 34       4
#4  6     4     5    48    42     0     0 78      21
```